# Convert Int To Hex

Tags: c#

I wrote this code to convert an integer number into hexadecimal number in VB C#.
On running the code, after I press the convert button the program stops responding and i have to use task manager to close it each time.I cant figure out why is it happening.Any help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public char value(byte x)
        {
            char[] arr = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
            return arr[x];
        }

        public void IntToHex(int num)
        {
            string HexString=" ";
            HexString = HexString.Trim();
            while(num>=0)
            {

                HexString+=value((byte)(num%16));
                num/=16;
            }
            HexText.Text += HexString;
            HexText.Enabled = false;
            Replay.Enabled = true;
            Quit.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 Integer;
            if (Int32.TryParse(IntegerText.Text, out Integer))
            {
                ConvertButton.Enabled = false;
                IntToHex(Integer);
            }
            else
            {
                HexText.Text = "Invalid Input.";
            }
        }

        public void Replay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IntegerText.Text = null;
            HexText.Text = null;
            IntegerText.Enabled = true;
            Replay.Enabled = false;
            Quit.Enabled = false;
            HexText.Enabled = false;
            ConvertButton.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void Quit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Hex` might do what you need. Despite the namespace, it can be used in C#

Comment: You are stuck in the while loop.

Comment: It should be obvious that the person cannot use inbuilt functions if he/she is writing THIS big code.

Comment: @SSS no reason to use VB legacy functions when a simple `ToString` with the proper format would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that below function have infinite loop.

```
public void IntToHex(int num)
    while(num>=0)
    {
        num/=16;   // never set num smaller than 0
    }
```

Comment: Better to remove the entire method and replace it with a simple `ToString` call. The method may not freeze but it still creates a lot of temporary strings. It should use `StringBuilder` at least to avoid wasting memory. Although, the method contains so many unnecessary code (eg Trim an empty string?) that it simply isn't worth using

Answer (score 4):

Why not use

```
int num = 42;
string hex = num.ToString("X");
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about it.